# How to set TCP_QUICKACK for Boost ASIO TCP socket

Tags: boost, tcp, boost-asio, asio

I am trying to set `TCP_QUICKACK` for my Boost TCP server/client application. I couldn't find the `TCP_QUICKACK` in Boost asio. How can I set this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Asio styled option for this. But you can always use the native handle:

```
// open tcp::socket s as normal...

int i = 1;
::setsockopt(s.native_handle(), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &i, sizeof(i));
```

I haven't tested it, but it looks like the following should work by defining your own non-portable option type:

```
using quickack = asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK>;
s.set_option(quickack(true));
```

I'd prefer the simple way that makes it clear that you're not promising any portable option.